# Reading feather files in apache arrow in c++

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

I need to read the data from feather file using apache arrow in C++.  I found a [Documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/dev/cpp/dataset.html) to read the file.  But, when running the code, it gave the following error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "vtable for arrow::dataset::FileFormat", referenced from:
      arrow::dataset::FileFormat::FileFormat() in libfeather.a(featherparser.cpp.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for arrow::dataset::IpcFileFormat", referenced from:
      arrow::dataset::IpcFileFormat::IpcFileFormat() in libfeather.a(featherparser.cpp.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After checking the code,  the error is due to the following line.

```
std::shared_ptr<ds::FileFormat> format = std::make_shared<ds::IpcFileFormat>();
```

I used `cmake`.  Following is my cmake file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(Main VERSION 1.0.0)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(Arrow QUIET)

add_library(feather src/include/featherparser.hpp src/include/featherparser.cpp)

# Executable...
add_executable(Main src/main.cpp)

# Target Libraries...
target_link_libraries(feather PRIVATE arrow_shared)
target_link_libraries(Main PRIVATE arrow_shared)
target_link_libraries(Main PRIVATE feather)
```

I am new to apache arrow and not sure whether the error is due to the linking in cmake.

Comment: gonna need to see the command used to compile and link

Comment: @pm100 I have added the cmake file used to compile and link the libraries

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Have you resolved the issue @Vignesh?